# Unable to use HTML Tags inside HtmlHelper::link()

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have the following link to generate the following link with helpers:

```
<a href="/rooms" class="ln-room">
    <span class="room-icon cls-icon"></span>
    <span class="lable">rooms</span>
</a>
```

I cannot supply the span tags inside `$combine`, as `HtmlHelper::link()` calls `htmlspecialchars_decode()`, thus converting all html to characters.

```
echo $this->Html->link($combine, array(
                                    'controller' => 'rooms',
                                    'action' => 'index'
                                 ),
                                 array('class' => 'ln-room')
                                 );
```

If the only way is to create a custom helper, how can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $this->Html->link($combine, array(
        'controller' => 'rooms',
        'action' => 'index'
    ),
    array(
        'class' => 'ln-room',
        'escape' => false  // <--- THIS
    )
);
```

Comment: Embarrassingly I missed it. Thank you. There is a small edit that needs to be made.

Comment: Yep - good catch - accepted your edit.  And np - it happens to the best of us :)